# Is it possible to see a summary for each persisted page request in Firebug?

Tags: firebug, network-analysis

I'm trying to get an overview of the *Persist* option in Firebug and I was only able to find a summary of bytes read and elapsed time for the last page request.

I wonder if there is a way to see the summaries side by side for all the page requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently (Firebug 2.x) not possible. I filed a bug for that several years ago:

[Issue #2757: Request summary in Net panel just shown for the last request when 'Persist' is enabled](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/2757)

Unfortunately it got never fixed.

Note that Firebug 3 [is meant to integrate into the built-in devtools](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2014/11/10/firebug-3-next-generation-of-firebug/) (and therefore inherit their features).
As they currently do not group the requests at all, I created [bug 1190213](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1190213) requesting the grouping per page.
Depending on that I filed [bug 1190216](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1190216) requesting to display the summary for each page.

Comment: Hi Sebastian sorry for not getting back to you sooner. I appreciate your answer and will mark it as one :-)

Comment: Thank you! I'm happy I could help you. So let's hope this will get implemented into the DevTools at some point.